# Как правильно изменять данные в компоненте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю React, пытаюсь написать простейшее приложении-блокнот с облачным сохранением заметок. Выглядит оно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, там всего два элемента - выпадающий список и поле с текстом.

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как прокинуть данные из выпадающего списка в поле для ввода. Пытался сделать вот так:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextEdit from './TextEdit';

class NoteSelect extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: this.props.notes[0],
      notes: this.props.notes
    };

    this.noteSelect = this.noteSelect.bind(this);
  }

  noteSelect(event) {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state); 

    let index = event.target.value;
    let _selected = this.state.notes[index];
    newState.selected = _selected;

    this.setState(newState);
  }

  editForm() {
    if (this.state.selected !== null) {
      return <TextEdit textObject={this.state.selected} />;
    } else {
      return (
        <article className="message is-info">
          <div className="message-body">
            Пожалуйста, выберите заметку
          </div>
        </article>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{margin: 30, marginTop: 15}}>
          <div className="field">
            <p className="control">
              <span className="select is-fullwidth">
                <select onChange={this.noteSelect}>
                  {this.props.notes.map((item, index) => 
                    <option value={index} key={index}>
                      {item.text}
                    </option>
                  )}
                </select>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            {this.editForm()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NoteSelect;
```

Но текст в компоненте TextEdit не меняется.

Код TextEdit:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TextEdit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: null,
      textObject: this.props.textObject
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    //this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
    console.log('created');
  }

  saveChanges() {
    console.log('Save changes');
  }

  setText(text) {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timer);
    this.saveChanges();

    this.setState({
      timer: null,
      value: text
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timer);

    this.setState({
      timer: setTimeout(this.saveChanges, 5000),
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p className="control">
        <textarea className="textarea" value={this.state.textObject.text} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type your text here!" />
      </p>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEdit;
```

Comment: Этот код рабочий. Вероятно, смотреть надо в компоненте TextEdit, каким именно образом вы выводите текст. Покажите код компонента TextEdit.

Comment: Дополнил. Код действительно рабочий, но при изменении инпута текст не меняется в TextEdit, в этом проблема =(

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете **textObject** как свойство и брать его нужно из **props**, а вы берете его из **state**. **state** - это локальное хранилище компонента. В вашем случае проще всего указывать значение сразу из **props**

```js
<textarea className="textarea" value={this.props.textObject.text} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type your text here!" />
```

Но если есть необходимость хранить его в **state** вы можете положить его туда явно из *componentWillReceiveProps* (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) примерно так:

```js
class TextEdit extends Component {
    ....

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const { textObject } = nextProps;

        if (textObject !== this.props.textObject) {
            this.setState({ textObject });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <p className="control">
            <textarea className="textarea" value={this.state.textObject.text} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type your text here!" />
          </p>
        );
    }
}
```